# How do I map a Table and a View to the same Entity in Spring JPA?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I’ve got a table which maps to an entity. Its logical primary key is a composite of two fields, id & revision. Instead of updating it, you create a new row with the same id and revision++.

I want to create a view representing the latest state of each id - so where `revision=max(revision)`. Then querying ought to be much simpler. But obviously when I query that view I want back instances of the same data class I have mapped to my original table.

Is that even possible with JPA?

Existing table, entity & repository:

```sql
create table data_snapshot(
    id varchar(44) not null,
    revision integer not null,
    data text not null,
    primary key (id, revision)
);
```

```kotlin
import java.io.Serializable
import javax.persistence.*
import org.hibernate.annotations.Immutable
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository

@Entity
@Immutable
@IdClass(DataSnapshotId::class)
@Table(name = "data_snapshot")
data class DataSnapshot(

  @Id
  val id: String,

  @Id
  val revision: Int,

  @Column
  val data: String,
)

@Embeddable
data class DataSnapshotId(val id: String, val revision: Int) : Serializable

interface DataSnapshotRepository : JpaRepository<DataSnapshot, DataSnapshotId> {
  // returns the latest snapshot for an id
  fun findFirstByIdOrderByRevisionDesc(id: String): DataSnapshot?
}
```

View I’m going to create:

```sql
create view latest_data_snapshot as
select data_snapshot.*
from data_snapshot
join (
  select id, max(revision) as latest_revision
  from data_snapshot
  group by id
) latest_snapshot
on data_snapshot.id = latest_snapshot.id
and data_snapshot.revision = latest_snapshot.latest_revision;
```

Which should allow a repository like this:

```
interface LatestDataSnapshotRepository : JpaRepository<DataSnapshot, String> {
  // returns the latest snapshot for an id
  fun findById(id: String): DataSnapshot?
}
```

except that I somehow need to let spring know that on this new repository it should be querying the `latest_data_snapshot` view, not the `data_snapshot` table...

Answer (score 0):

A colleague suggests just adding a method to the existing repository with a custom `@Query` on it to query the view, which seems a simple and effective way of doing it:

```kotlin
interface DataSnapshotRepository : JpaRepository<DataSnapshot, DataSnapshotId> {
  // returns the latest snapshot for an id
  fun findFirstByIdOrderByRevisionDesc(id: String): DataSnapshot?

  // also returns the latest snapshot for an id
  @Query(
    value = "select * from latest_data_snapshot where id = :id",
    nativeQuery = true
  )
  fun findLatestById(@Param("id") id: String): DataSnapshot?
}
```

Not quite as nice as Spring doing all the work based on the method name, but I haven't yet found a way to make that happen.